# Stream screen to Chromecast

Tags: google-cast

I am trying to create an App to Stream screen to Chromecast.
I follow the Tutorials and able to create button & connect device.
However, what is next step to cast over ?

Anyone know how using the latest Android Sender 17.1.0 ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should register your receiver app and a Cast device to test (https://cast.google.com). Anyway, I guess you have your mediaRouteIMenuItem created.

Now you have to use **RemoteMediaClient** to load some content in your cast device (Video, audio...). What's your problem exactly?

Answer (score 0):

I have an App require to cast the screen (mirror) to the Chromecast or other similar device.  I notice in SDK-28 Phone which I use for testing, the Android-OS already has this feature.

Could I could simply invoke(control) this Android feature within my App using API ?  I could not find how to do it.

Furthermore reading the material, it indicates if I am using default Cast device protocol, I could just use the "CastMediaControlIntent.DEFAULT_MEDIA_RECEIVER_APPLICATION_ID" =  "CC1AD845".
Is this correct ?

I found a project "android_library_screen_mirroring_chromecast-master" in GitHub created 2 years ago to use "CastScreenPresentation" but when I rebuild the project using "com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0" and it would not work.